# Files in "/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/" taking a lot of space, how to free it?

Tags: disk-usage

Contents of /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:

`$ du -sh * |grep G`

```
1,6G    libwebkit2gtk-3.0.so.25.10.11
1,4G    libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0.22.14
1,3G    webkit2gtk-3.0
```

my / partition is only 15gb and almost full (df -h):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5        19G   15G  3,2G  82% /
```

I found that the last file (webkit2gtk) belongs to the package libwebkitgtk-3.0-0-dbg, still not sure what the others are. How can I tell which package uses these files and how can I know if they are 'safe' to remove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `dpkg -S` (or equivalently `dpkg-query -S`) to identify the package to which a file belongs

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebkit2gtk-3.0.so.25.10.11
```

In this case, it seems to belong to libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25-dbg

AFAIK `-dbg` packages are only required if you need to debug into the corresponding library functions: if you are not developing / debugging webkit2gtk-3.0 applications I don't see why you shouldn't remove them. If in doubt, you can always run the package manager in 'dry run' mode to see if any important dependent packages are going to be removed as a result

```
sudo apt-get remove --dry-run libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25-dbg
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I removed both packages (libwebkitgtk-3.0-0-dbg and libwebkit2gtk-3.0-25-dbg) so far it seems that everything is ok, and I have 5GB more on /.
I can't even upvote this answer on account of my low reputation. BTW, no need for sudo when performing a dry-run :)